# Can bitcoin be forked in such way that the monetary base increase?

Tags: bitcoin-core, blockchain-fork, money-supply

Can it be forked into a new coin, such that if i had X bitcoins i will still have X coins in the new crypto-coin, but the monetary base will be 50M coins for example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It's possible to do that in a not backward compatible fork (hardfork).

Assumed that the new currency would be bitcoin50 (B50):

You could copy the whole Bitcoin-blockchain (as in every hardfork) but only modify (increase) the future block rewards so that there are around 50,000,000 B50`s available when the reward is 0 in ~100 years.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Isn't it kind of a threat to the value of bitcoin? What prevent some powerful personals in the bitcoin community to do something like this in the future, just because there is some economic need to increase the monetary base? in the same why we abandoned the gold standard.

Comment: Well, you can be sure that someone tried something like this in the past. But remember: There is only 1 original bitcoin. And if the new currency with 50,000,000 coins is published: Why should you trust it? The developers behind it could also say 1 year later: What about 100,000,000 coins? Furthermore you need to convince a large part of the bitcoin-people. Otherwise, the b50-coins is irrelevant/worthless.